# Magento 2 - Move Layered Navigation above products

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Currently my Layered Navigation on mobile is under the products. On a large Category we have 60 Products displayed with additional filters for the layered navgiation. Since the users cant find the filter options I want to move it above the products to make it visible for everyone.

For some reason i dont know where to start, is there anyone who could help me with that?

Magento Version: 2.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested below code .. But should do the job. Basically we need to move "catalog.leftnav (catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml)" block from side  to content.

Add below to your local theme Magento_LayeredNavigation/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="category.products" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: That works like a charm, but unfortunalty it also changed on the desktop layout. Is there a way to make that only for mobile?

Comment: If you only need to change order in Mobile, the you can do it via CSS order property, that's one ways of doing it . Or else using jquery/javascript we can move div container. I would prefer  CSS order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code anything; just change the 2-column design to 1-column design,
from the category admin panel and it will automatically move to the top of the product grid.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qlBy.png)

[image]

Or You can change 1 colomn design from xml also.

```
    <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template> 
   </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```